# Adding and retrieving cells to dictionary losing cell info swift3

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, dictionary

I am using a dictionary to store cells from a table view on `cellForRowAt:`, and then when the textField in the cell finishes editing, i'm updating the contents of the dictionary to reflect the new cell.  This is so that when the cell scrolls off the screen, and then back in the entered value is still displayed.

When `cellForRowAt:` is called again I retrieve the cell from the dictionary and return it, however the returned cell's textField doesn't contain any information.

I have tested this by retrieving the cell from the dictionary in the same method as when it is put there, and the textField text is still there.

This is the code that replaced the cell after the textField changes:

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if textField.tag == 0 {
        print("Replacing value in tableCells")
        let tempCell = tableCells["\(textField.tag)"] as! profileNameCell
        tempCell.profileName.text = textField.text
        tableCells["\(textField.tag)"] = tempCell
    } else {
        let tempCell = tableCells["\(textField.tag)"] as! profileInfoCell
        tempCell.infoField.text = textField.text
        tableCells["\(textField.tag)"] = tempCell
    }
}
```

This is the code in `cellForRowAt:`:

```
let indexString = "\(indexPath.row)"

if tableCells[indexString] as! UITableViewCell == cellFiller {
    print("Replacing tableCells[\(indexString)] with cell")
    tableCells[indexString] = cell
    return cell
} else {
    print("Returning contents of tableCells[\(indexString)]")
    let replacementCell = tableCells[indexString] as! profileNameCell
    print("tableCells[\(indexString)] name info = \(replacementCell.profileName.text ?? "")")
    return replacementCell
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't manage the cells yourself, that's what a `UITableViewController` is for.  Cells are reused, so you might have ended up adding the same cell to different tag keys in your dictionary.

Instead, manage a model, and let `cellForRow` use the model to configure your cells.

I wouldn't always suggest using tagging to track your text fields but for sake of brevity, this will do.  Just kind of making this up off the top of my head, let me know if you have issues.

```
//definition
var strings = ["One", "Two", "Three"]

//number of sections
return 1

//number of rows
return strings.count

//cell for row - make a custom table cell with a textfield
cell.textField.text = self.strings[indexPath.row]
cell.textField.tag = indexPath.row

//textfield did end editing
strings[textField.tag] = textField.text
tableView.reloadData()
```

You can also do it with a dictionary instead.

Comment: Perfect - worked a treat, I used a dictionary instead of an array as each cell in the table is part of a profile creation field and I didn't want them to get out of order.